# Did Bilaam have free will?

Tags: speech-talking, parashat-balak, free-will-bechira, curse

By God preventing Bilaam from cursing the Jews, was that not an impingement of Bilaams free will?

Comment: Bil'am chooses to "say whatever God says".

Comment: -1, no context indicating where God did so.

Comment: guys, if you don't know the answer, just say so

Comment: @BoelShamusToova Suppose it was. What's the problem?

Comment: Possible dup? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/did-hardening-paros-heart-mean-he-wasnt-really-responsible?rq=1  (There are additional considerations there beyond just the free-will question.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, not really a duplicate: one's about _Par'o_ and one's about _Bil'am_, and they may have completely disparate answers.

Comment: To add to my previous comment; see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18063/1601

Answer (score 2):

Bilaam had free will - but he also had a heightened awareness of Gcd's presence.

As a prophet he was acutely aware of Gcd's ability to punish; and he even got a "refresher course" on his journey, in the episode with his talking donkey.

Compare it to this: You find a perfect spot to park - but it's there's a no-parking sign and a policeman standing nearby. Would you consider that an impingement of your free will?

Of course not! You are simply in a situation with a heightened awareness of the law's ability to punish you.

Both you and Bilaam have the physical ability to do whatever they please - park or curse - so you have free will. But you both realize the consequences of making the wrong choice.

See [this Q&A](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/did-hardening-paros-heart-mean-he-wasnt-really-responsible?rq=1) for a similar idea with Paro's free will.

Comment: In particular, this answer there: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12202/472 .

Comment: Any source for this explanation?