# Why did g_d harden Pharaoh's heart?

Tags: tanach

Why did g_d harden Pharaoh's heart
when he had to get the Israelites free later?

did he want to show them
that he is the almighty omniscient
or something else?

Comment: Welcoem to Mi Yodeya. This is a very good and important question. Many people have asked this over time. I think we have an answer to this on this site, but I need to hunt. Briefly, your 2nd question is a main part of the answer. I'll have to hunt the verse that supports this.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/did-hardening-paros-heart-mean-he-wasnt-really-responsible

Comment: related but not same .-.

Comment: The related question, I think, provides further understanding and supplements my answer.

Comment: related (or duplicate?) of [What does it mean that God hardened Pharaoh’s heart?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/what-does-it-mean-that-god-hardened-pharaoh-s-heart)

Comment: @mbloch related but I don't see it as a dupe. I think OP is looking for a more "basic" understanding, here. I think he's asking about the reason for using this specific method and not about the effect of the method.

Comment: "when he had to get the Israelites free later" - Please clarify who is "he" - Pharaoh or G-d? I assume you mean G-d.

Comment: obviously G-d..

Answer (score 1):

There are a few key verses.

First [Shemot (Ex.) 3:19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=44) - G-d tells Moses, "I know that Pharoah won't allow you to leave unless I show him my strong hand." It seems a given that unless he was shown G-d's might, Pharoah was in full control of things. So, he had to be "punished" in some way. But, of course, it doesn't directly address why G-d hardens his heart to do this job (showing G-d's might). BTW, look at [Shemot 5:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=60&hilite=) where Pharaoh asks who is this "adon-ai" that I should listen to him? So, it's clear that G-d had to show him something.

In [Shemot 7:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=90&hilite=) G-d says that he will harden Pharaoh's heart so that he can increase his wonders in Egypt.

Rash"i explains that G-d determined that it had already been reveled that he would not do *teshuva* from his evil ways. Therefore, it is appropriate that he hardens Pharaoh's heart so that he would understand my strength. He states that G-d's method is to bring punishments on the idolatrous nations of the world in order that Israel observe and fear G-d (and not imitate this behavior.)

*Siftei Chachamim* expands on this concept further. He says that G-d says that if I didn't harden his heart and just brought about the plagues, people might think that G-d punishes people who do *teshuva*. But I (g-d) know that he won't repent with a full heart. Therefore, I have to harden his heart so that others will understand the reason for the plagues that follow. Note that *Siftei Chachamim* tries to explain Rashi's explanation on G-d's method also because the verse implies that G-d wants to increase the punishments beyond the measure of the actual sin. See the source.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different points that are made in the various answers.

1. Pharaoh at first hardened his own heart in order to withstand the earlier plagues. Once he had established the pattern, Hashem allowed him to continue in that pattern by *hardening* later to be able to resist the later plagues.
2. Hashem only strengthened Pharaoh so that he could make an independent decision at all times. That is, He was trying to allow Pharaoh to *do the right thing* of his own free will. Pharaoh refused to take advantage of that opportunity.
3. Pharaoh, by consistently refusing to send them out of his own free will, forfeited the ability to choose as the final punishment had been decreed. Once he reached that level of evil, he could not turn back.

See what I answer at [What does it mean that God hardened Pharaoh’s heart?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/what-does-it-mean-that-god-hardened-pharaoh-s-heart).

There are a number of answers ranging from strengthening Pharaoh so that he could withstand the plagues, to the difference in language showing that Pharaoh hardened his own heart at first and G0d only did that later after Pharaoh had reached the level of requiring punishment, ...

Check out [Hardened Hearts: Some Explanations](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/beliefs/Theology/Free_Will/Responses/Medieval/Hardened_Hearts.shtml?p=0) to see some of them Reinterpretation of the Term (Saadiah Gaon), The Modest Solution (Ramban), The Bold Claim: Pharaoh Acts Freely (Albo), Hardening as Punishment (Rambam)

[Pharaoh's Heart](http://www.aish.com/tp/i/moha/48937417.html) goes into detail on the theme of Pharaoh having reached a level through his own free will in which this was an appropriate punishment.

An interesting point is that the word for 'harden' is actually 'heavy'. The Egyptian superstition was that when being judged after death, a person's heart was weighed against a feather (the feather of Truth IIRC). If the heart was lighter, he was judged innocent. Thus, Pharaoh hardening his own heart can mean that he was guilty **even in terms of his own beliefs**. Hashem hardening his heart can therefore mean that Pharaoh is now punished by those means or that his refusal (in his own terms) to repent causes him to lose the ability to repent, or by moving along the path of error he has that much farther to go to return, ...

Rav Shimshon Rafael Hirsch prefers the idea that Hashem helped strengthen Pharaoh so that he had free will and could make a totally objective decision. He prefers the meaning to be 'strengthen' rather than 'harden'.

Also note @Fred giving the pointers

> Also, for some examples of articles that discuss some of the major
>   views among the rishonim on this, see
>   [here](http://www.shaalvim.org/sfw/shiurim/view.asp?id=643),
>   [here](http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2013/01/pharoahs-loss-of-bechira-ramban-lshitaso.html),
>   [here](http://doleh-u-mashkeh.blogspot.com/2013/12/bechira-chofshis-2.html),
>   and
>   [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/730430/Rabbi_David_Horwitz/Parashat__Bo:_Rambam%E2%80%99s_Resolution_of_the_Antinomy_of_Human_Free_Will_and_God%E2%80%99s__Hardening_of_Pharaoh%E2%80%99s_Heart)

Comment: hey doesnt hardening his heart mean making him stop feeling kind? so how did it help Pharaoh withstand the plague? 

Comment: @user39122 kind is modern usage. Torah usage is strength of will and desires. See lo sasuru acharei levavchem.

Comment: so hardening his heart has nothing to do with pharaoh not releasing them?

Comment: No it has everything to do with it. I said that his will was strengthened so that he could decide not to release them and not succumb to the pressure of the plagues like someone with a gun to his head. The analogy has nothing to do with *kindness* as the modern usage of heart might have it.

Comment: yes and this is what i asked when g_d wanted to get Israelites free then why did he have to harden his heart

Comment: As I explained, Hashem wanted to have Pharaoh make a free willed decision to let them go. If He had created a miracle to move them from Egypt into the desert, they would not have been *freed* at all. Pharaoh had to be influenced to send them out himself. A man with a gun to his head cannot be punished for eating non-kosher food.

Comment: @user39122 See my explanation above. If Hashem had not allowed Pharaoh free will during the plagues they would never have gotten over being slaves. At that it took the entire next generation before they could enter the land.

Comment: does strengthening the will mean increasing the power to resist in this context?

Comment: @user39122 Yes. That is, a person can only resist pressure based on the strength of his will and the ability to overcome the pain. Imagine someone with a gun to his head resisting the demands of the person holding the gun.

Comment: that seems impossible. Anyone who has an urge to live would definitely do anything at that time that the person holding the gun wants him to do

Comment: @user39122 That was an analogy. Substitute financial pressure, threats or anything else. In any case consider Chananiah Mishael and Azaryah as other examples who were willing to be thrown into the fire, but said they might not have been able to withstand torture. Daniel and the Lion's den, Avraham in the fire of Ur Kasdim. Pharaoh did muster the will to resist until the tenth plague.

Comment: what if g_d hadn't hardened his heart.  then these plagues and mass murder won't be needed. many lives could have been saved. Pharaoh would give up at 4th or 5th plague and release the Israelites

Comment: @user39122 Not necessarily. Hypothetical questions do not have valid answers. The point is that we do not know what would have happened. Had Pharaoh been forced early they would not have been free.